# Почему var name всегда string

Tags: javascript

Случайно нашел странную штуку в JS:

```js
var name = ['123', '321'];
console.log(typeof name);
```

Всегда будет string (кроме IE). Но, если создать через `let`, то оно нормально себя ведет... что это?

Добавлено

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Это из-за этого `window.name`?

Comment: поясните, что тут будет string ?

Comment: @teran в `name` будет стринг

Comment: для массива вообще `object` согласно документации должно возвращать. и если `name` переименовать во что-то другое, то результат будет как в документации. связано с `window.name`, да.